# How do you scan a barcode and display it in 2 different textfields (IOS xcode 4, Linea-Pro 4)

Tags: xcode, barcode-scanner, uitextfielddelegate, linea-pro

I've been stuck on this topic for a last few days. I'm trying to scan a barcode and have it displayed in two different textfields. As of now, I can scan the barcode, but it displays the full barcode in each textfield. I need it to be like this…
example :

Barcode 123-123456-001 ( Barcode has value,  ex: 123 = game number, 123456 = book number, 001 = ticket number in sequence

123= 1st textfield

123456= second textfield

001 = nil (for now, will be used later)

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you for any suggestion or help!

Comment: well, for what its worth. I finally figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share your answer, I will post one.

Using the componentsSeparatedByString: function on the returned NSString will give you an array of NSString objects. Simply put the correct objects into the correct textfields after that.